# How do I find audio files with no or invalid extension in Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, search

I am trying to search for some audio files that I recorded 25 years ago... they are amongst literally millions of files. These 2 files have random names and random extensions. Is there a search method to search contents of files to find audio files?

EDIT: I do not know if they are wav or mp3 files... they were work voicemails I transferred from a voicemail system that I recorded to my machine. Then I renamed them with just some letters and numbers so that they did not stand out as audio files when the company scanned my drive each night. They would likely be wav or mp3. This was back in 1999 and there is some info I need from them now.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To expand on the Bot's comment above, surely there is something useful you could tell about the files: are they wav or mp3: you could use a process that checks the file header. Is the file extension *actually* random: find the least-used file extension on the filesystem and check those. Is there actually *no extension* look at those.

Comment: 'no extension' was probably just Windows being its usual helpful self & hiding them If you even know what app they were made by you'd have a start. Otherwise, if they're just generic wav, mp3 etc they very probably have a recognisable extension.

Comment: Unfortunately... I hid them. Amongst my source code files. Which, over 30 years of developing is an insanely large amount of files. I may have even given them vb 6 .bas or .frm extensions just to hide them.

Comment: In Linux the `file` command can analyze a file. With the power of `find` it's relatively easy to find files identified as audio, but with non-matching extension. Can you use Linux? Can you use a distro with `file` supporting `--mime-type`?

Comment: That may be worth a shot! I will see if I can try a linux box.

Comment: On Windows you can use TrID which will also try to guess file type by its contents.

Comment: Ok... just downloaded that... will try it. :)

Comment: With GNU `find` and powerful enough `file`: `find . -type f ! -iname '*.wav' ! -iname '*.mp3' -exec sh -c 'for f do mime="$(file -b --mime-type "$f")"; [ "${mime%/*}" = audio ] && printf "%s\\n" "$f"; done' find-sh {} +`. Add more `! -iname '*.something'` exclusions at will (important: *before* `-exec`). If I were you, I would first test the command in a directory with a test extensionless/misnamed audio file.

Comment: I will try these recommendations in a few moments. Thank you so much! My next step was going to be to write my own program to do it... but that would take longer, lol.

Comment: Thank you for all of your advice... installing CYGWIN64 and running Unix/Linux commands made a big difference! It is still running, but I think it will get me the data I need. Ran command as **find ./Personal -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep -e WAV -e Audio -e MPEG -> output.txt** That will at least give me something I can dig through in Excel...  I will tighten up the search later with the **! -iname** functions later. *Thank you* for the wonderful ideas!